# How do I maintain Fragment data during orientation change?

Tags: android, screen-orientation, android-bluetooth

I have an application using Bluetooth.  My UI displays are going to be made up from a number of separate displays, each implemented as a Fragment.  Some of these are relatively complex and I want to be able to rearrange the displays according to the orientation.

I have to disable the activity shutdown as if I don't the Bluetooth connection is dropped.

I have tried a number of the recommended steps to try and manage the changeover of orientation from Landscape to Portrait and vice versa.  Using a Bundle to transfer data from the old to the new drops Bluetooth.

If I use setRetainInstance(true); in my Fragment, I can successfully change the display without dropping the Bluetooth connection, but the process involves inflating and creating a new version of the layout. Information from the previous instance is not passed to the revised layout, and the new layout is inactive (eg, pressing buttons indicates correctly on the screen but does not change anything in the parent Activity).  It seems that I am creating a new instance which is not connected to the Activity.

I have also tried testing the orientation and using getRequestedOrientation()/setRequestedOrientation() to change orientation programmatically.  This keeps the same instance of the Fragment with data but doesn't change orientation - do I need to issue a command to redraw after this?

Any suggestions will be gratefully received.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved - and comparatively easily.

1. In the Manifest, use android:configChanges = "orientation|screenSize" as part of the     main Activity configuration.
2. There is no need to use setRetainInstance(true); in the Fragment onCreateView - it     doesn't appear to make any difference.
3. In Activity onCreate the fragments are added then hidden:

   ```
   // Set up the window layout
   setContentView(R.layout.index_page_layout);
   // Add the fragments and hide them.

   FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
   FragmentTransaction fragTrans = fm.beginTransaction();

   fragTrans.add(R.id.container, hmi1,"HMI1");
   fragTrans.hide(hmi1);
   fragTrans.add(R.id.container, hmi2,"HMI2");
   fragTrans.hide(hmi2);
   fragTrans.add(R.id.container, termfrag,"TERM");
   fragTrans.hide(termfrag);
   fragTrans.commit();
   hmi1_showing = false;
   hmi2_showing = false;
   terminal_showing = false;
   ```

   No special actions are taken in the Activity onConfigurationChanged.
4. In the Fragment onConfigurationChanged, I have:

   ```
   Fragment currentFragment = getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("FRAGTAG");
   FragmentTransaction fragTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
   fragTransaction.detach(currentFragment);
   fragTransaction.attach(currentFragment);
   fragTransaction.commit();
   ```

   where FRAGTAG is the relevant Tag as defined in the Activity.onCreate method.